# Angular 2 - how to use the new angular 2.0.0-rc.1 router

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I've started to write a new angular 2 project and I found that I installed 2 angular router:

1. `"@angular/router":  "2.0.0-rc.1"`,
2. `"@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.1"`,

I didn't find in the angular site how to use the new router. For example, what component do I need to import.

So my questions are:

1. Should I use the `router-deprecated`?
2. Is there any good doc for how to use the new router?

Comment: https://github.com/app4pc/angular2-bible.git  is now with new route

Comment: Note though, that as mentioned in the comments to the following article, this "new" RC.1 router is already being deprecated and rewritten again. (I'd be interested in the source of this statement though) https://playcode.org/routing-in-angular-2-rc-1/

Comment: @netmikey there's a statement [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9080#issuecomment-224567417) which points to [this repo](https://github.com/angular/vladivostok). I haven't been able to find the discussion that lead to this.

Comment: Finally, there's some official explanation: http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/06/improvements-coming-for-routing-in.html

Answer (score 38):

**Here is how to use the Angular 2 Router (RC1), compared to the beta (deprecated) one:**

- `Routes` replaces `RouteConfig`.
- Inside your config there is a new syntax:

  `{path: '/path', component: MyPathComponent}`

  instead of:

  `{path:'/path', name: 'MyPath', component: MyPathComponent}`
- Using routerLink is now like that:

  `<a [routerLink]="['/path/2']">Click to navigate</a>`

  Instead of:

`<a [routerLink]="['MyPath', 'Detail', {id:2}]">Shark Crisis</a>`

- Also there is no `RouteParams` anymore, instead you get the params using
  the router lifecycle hooks: `CanActivate`, `OnActivate`, and
  `CanDeactivate`.

If you used params inside `ngOnInit`, you can do that like this now:

```
routerOnActivate(curr: RouteSegment): void {
           curr.getParam('id');
       }
```

You will end up having something like this:

```
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router, Routes} from "@angular/router";

@Injectable()
@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: `<a [routerLink]="['/component1']">Click to go to component 1</a>`,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
@Routes([
    {path: "/component1", component: Component1},
    {path: "/component2", component: Component2}
])
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private _router: Router) {
        //If you want to use Router in your component (for navigation etc), you can inject it like this
    }
}
```

**Update (9/6/16):**
It seems that Angular 2 RC1 Router is being deprecated like the old one.
The new recommendation is to use version 3.0.0-alpha.3 of @angular/router.

Here is more info at the Angular blog:
http://angularjs.blogspot.co.il/2016/06/improvements-coming-for-routing-in.html

Here is an overview of the new router:
http://victorsavkin.com/post/145672529346/angular-router

And here is a working plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ER0tf8fpGHZiuVWB7Q07?p=preview

Comment: It became also deprecated, here is an upgrade guide to the newest: https://medium.com/@blacksonic86/upgrading-to-the-new-angular-2-router-255605d9da26

Comment: Witch version of angular's router the post above is talking to ? RC1 of 2.0.0 or RC1 of 3.0.0 ?

Comment: The version is 2.0.0

Answer (score 11):

This helped me get started with the new router:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

**EDIT:** Above link is empty for now.. cached version thanks to tylerjgarland: https://web.archive.org/web/20160416143350/https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

I also found Misko Hevery's router talk from ng-conf helpful:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d8yAdeshpcw

**UPDATE:** It appears that the RC1 Router is being abandoned?
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9088
Perhaps that is why the docs disappeared rather than being completed...

**UPDATE 2:** The RC2 Router has now been released:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

> The Component Router is in alpha release. This is the recommended Angular 2 router and supersedes the earlier deprecated beta and v2 routers.

this line in `package.json` for the new alpha router:

```
"@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.7",
```

as I found out here: [Installing Angular 2 RC2 w/ new component router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924912/installing-angular-2-rc2-w-new-component-router)

Comment: "This chapter is a work in progress". I'm guessing that documentation will be helpful at some point, but not right now.

Comment: @Steve, thanks for confirming. I distinctly remember using this page a few weeks ago.

Here's a cached view. https://web.archive.org/web/20160416143350/https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Answer (score 6):

Here is another resource you can try (Angular RC.1): https://playcode.org/routing-in-angular-2-rc-1/

And here is the code: https://github.com/jlsuarezs/RoutingExample

I recommend you to use the Angular-CLI to create new routes: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Example: 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#generating-a-route

Answer (score 5):

New Angular 2 router documentation and development work in progress. till that you can use "@angular/router-deprecated".

@AkhileshKumar suggestion is good, try that out i think its all cover basic router usage.

Answer (score 4):

**update for RC.1**

The new router `@angular/router` of Angular2 RC.1 is deprecated.
The Angular team is working on providing a new router again.
It was suggested to stay with the old `@angular/router-deprecated` router until this new new router becomes available

**original**

The docs for the new router are work in progress. See for example https://github.com/angular/angular.io/pull/1214

The new router has a few issues but in overall is working fine already. If you don't just want to learn about how to use it, I'd wait at least for the next Angular RC version. There are some early adopters that reported a few issues where most are probably easy to fix.

Answer (score 3):

Working nested routeing code for angular2: "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1" i.e. with new router are as follows:

Parent Route:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Router,Routes,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';

import {Login} from '../login/login';
import {Dashboard} from '../dashboard/dashboard';
import {Admin} from '../admin/admin';
let template = require('./app.html');

@Component({
  selector: 'auth-app',
  template: template,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
})

@Routes([
  {path: '/login', component: Login},
  {path: '/dashboard', component: Dashboard},
  {path: '/admin', component: Admin }
])

export class App{
  constructor(public router: Router) {
  }
}
```

Child Route

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';
import { Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ,Routes} from '@angular/router';

import {AddUsrCat} from './addUsrCat/addUsrCat';
import {AllUsr} from './allUsr/allUsr';
declare var jQuery:JQueryStatic;
let template = require('./admin.html');

@Component({
  selector: 'admin',
  directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  template: template
})
@Routes([
  {path: '/addUsrCat', component: AddUsrCat},
  {path: '/allUsr', component: AllUsr},
  {path: '*', component: AddUsrCat},
])

export class Admin {
  constructor(public router: Router, public http: Http) {
  }
}
```

Clone this project [A  basic Angular2 ("2.0.0-rc.1") project with authentication (login / logout) works as seed project](https://github.com/app4pc/angular2-bible.git) which uses **@angular/router** i.e. new route

Comment: That uses `@angular/router-deprecated` which is not the new Angular2 RC.1 router.

Comment: He's asking how to use the new router, not the old router.