# Installing Angular 2 RC2 w/ new component router

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm probably missing something simple, but trying to use the new Component Router I can't get VS Code to recognize it.

I changed all my `@angular` references in `package.json` to `2.0.0-rc.2`; ran npm install and VS Code doesn't like my imports:

[image]

When I navigate to the `@angular/router` folder in `node_modules`, and inspect the `index.d.ts` I see all the references for the RC1 router. Removed the `@angular` folder and installed again, same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the new release of angular rc2. The version of router to install is

`"@angular/router" : "3.0.0-alpha.6" or
 "@angular/router" : "3.0.0-alpha.7"`

The repo for the router is at https://github.com/angular/vladivostok . The docs on the site https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html are on `alpha.6`. I would advice to go through the changelog to know about breaking changes when using `alpha.7`

Comment: For future reference: The repository was merged into https://github.com/angular/angular - but all the issues (some with useful information and instructions) are now gone.

Answer (score 2):

If you just started to work with Angular router, I suggest you disregard RC1 router and start with the new [router v3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/router).

```
"@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.7"
```

Here is the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) for Router v3.

Comment: I've done exactly this, like the quickstart suggests. When loading the app in the browser, I'm getting 404s on several `.umd.js` files (which didn't happen in rc1) causing the app to not load at all.

Answer (score 0):

The router is not maintained as a separate project anymore. It has been recently merged into Angular2 and the router is now in beta.. I would suggest you to use start using the beta by adding a dependency in your package.json file
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2"

Answer (score 0):

it is now at V3.RC1. So please update your package.json accordingly

"@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",

You might also have to upgrade your application to Angular2.RC5 and change the way routing is done.